# Will Spring Session persist Web Flow state?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-session

I have a couple of wizards that seem like a good fit for Spring Web Flow, but Web Flow stores significant flow state server-side, and I'm not sure where. I'm using a rapid integration and deployment cycle, so durability across server restarts is a must.

I think that Web Flow uses the `SessionBindingConversationManager` to store flow state in the `HttpSession`, and so Spring Session will persist that state into the external session store. Is this correct? If so, do I need to do anything besides configuring Spring Session and adding the Web Flow components to my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Web Flow stores conversation state in the `HttpSession` in the `webflowConversationContainer` attribute. Spring Session will persist this to an external store, and servers sharing the session repository will have synchronized state for flows.